# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I was looking at other examples but I have not opened anything, where would I close the information at. It happenes when I go to _DBContext.SaveChanges();
Additionally, the code says if the Wedding is less then DateTimeNow to do this action, however, it does it for all dates. I have read throuhg many questions and answers they are all pretty different to me as a newbie trying to make a method in the controller. Should I be making this method in the conroller or somewhere else?

```cs
// Delete old weddings from comparing date times 
     public void DeleteOldWeddings()
      {
            foreach (Wedding date in _DBContext.Weddings)
         {
                var result = DateTime.Compare(date.WedDate, DateTime.Now);
                if (result < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This " + date.UserID);
                    _DBContext.Weddings.Remove(date);
                    _DBContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enumerator for your foreach loop is what’s open.  Call .ToArray() or similar to finish reading the query results before attempting another operation with the DbContext.

```
foreach(var date in _DBContext.Weddings.ToArray())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh I did not know that I will try this right away. I didn't understand thant thank you :)

Comment: Also, is the controller the proper place to put this method or should I have put it somewhere else?

Comment: I put .ToList(); but it works thank you so much that made it so easy for me. So adding a Weddings opens it, and adding .ToList() or .ToArray() closes it thank you so much I was on this for like 2 days LOL :)